# How to use Timer in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want use matlab to get IBM price from yahoo
price can get by

```
quote = fetch(yahoo, 'IBM', 'Last');
px = quote.Last;
```

Now I want to retrieve the data every minute from, for example, 9:00 am to 1:00 pm.
I would like to use timer object to get my data.

However, I cannot figure out how to use it.
What I can get is

```
t = timer;
t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';
t.Period = 60;
```

especially the `timerFcn`, I don't get how to use it.

Hope someone can write me an example with this.
Thanks

Comment: `timerFcn` is the function you ant to execute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write a callback function to use `TimerFcn`.

Let this be your main file, where you initiate the timer:

```
tmr = timer('ExecutionMode', 'FixedRate', ...
    'Period', 60, ...
    'TimerFcn', {@timerCallback});
start(tmr);
```

Then this would be your callback function, which would execute every time the timer count is complete (i.e. every 60 seconds in your example).

```
function timerCallback(hObj, eventdata)
    disp('timey-wimey');
end
```